# Get the position of word pairs in a string of words

Tags: c#, string, delimiter

I have a string of words:

```
spring java spring spring spring javescript java jboss jboss tomcat jboss
```

I have to break up this string using a space as the delimiter, then i two types of pairs I need to find

1. Combo-pair
2. Next-To-Pair

I know how to break up the words

```
string text = "spring java spring spring spring javescript java jboss jboss tomcat jboss";
string[] list = text.Split(' ');
```

and it works fine, but I don't know where to start on finding the pairs, the output should be like this:

spring: 6 Combo-pairs(0,2)(0,3)(0,4)(2,4)(3,4) and 2 next-to-pairs (2,3)(3,4)

so in short it must print out the word and then the position of all the other words identical to in relation to it, then continue to the next word and print the position of the rest in relation to the new word, I tried adding each word to a Dictionary and their index to another dictionary and compare them from the original array and get the index but I get so confused and I have no idea what to do or where to start, any advice or maybe a direction to look into ? I don't want the answer I just want a guideline if possible ?

Comment: is that the exact output you have provided? I say to clear it up add the exact output in a code block in a string like `expectedOutput = "  . . .   "`

Comment: what about the combo-pair: (2,3) ?

Comment: For combo-pairs, for each element in the array look forward to find the index of a match. For next-to-pairs, for each element in the array see if the next element is the same.

Comment: @Mong Zhu it seems I forgot that one.

Comment: @Adam but how do I get the position of each word for the output, thats my main problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it ...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
```

Define a container for each result item ...

```
        class IndexPair
        {
            public int Index1 { get; set; }
            public int Index2 { get; set; }
        }
```

Ok lets do this ...

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
```

Declare the string we want to test against and some result sets to store the results ...

```
            var testString = "spring java spring spring spring javescript java jboss jboss tomcat jboss";
            var test = testString.Split(' ');
            var pairs = new List<IndexPair>();
            var comboPairs = new List<IndexPair>();
```

Loop through the source array (variable "test") and ask the appropriate questions ...

```
            for (int i = 0; i < test.Length; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < test.Length; j++)
                    if (j > i && test[i] == test[j])
                    {
                        var pair = new IndexPair { Index1 = i, Index2 = j };
                        pairs.Add(pair);

                        if (j == (i + 1)) comboPairs.Add(pair);
                    }
```

Output the results ...

```
            Console.WriteLine("Input string: " + testString);
            Console.WriteLine("Word pairs: " + string.Join(" ", pairs.Select(p => $"{p.Index1},{p.Index2}")));
            Console.WriteLine("Combo pairs: " + string.Join(" ", comboPairs.Select(p => $"{p.Index1},{p.Index2}")));
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

... seems to give the expected output at least (even though the question didn't quite pick up on all matches).

Hopefully if you followed that right you should have realised that all the code from this answer combined is a full console app that will achieve what you want when run.

Comment: It works, I just need to combine the output so that it prints the results for the specific word instead of printing the result for the specific pair, but it does give me the required output

Comment: are you saying you want the words with the indexes?

Answer (score 0):

There are complex ways to do it, the easily understandable one would be:

```
string[] words = text.Split(' ');
for(int i=0; i<words.Length; i++){
  for(int j=i+1; j<words.length; j++){
    if(words[i] == words[j]){
      //You have a match, do your stuff here!
    }
  }
}
```

What you'd do is for each word, check the next word and onwards until the end of the text for matches and note down their indexes (i and j respectively).

And this for combos:

```
string[] words = text.Split(' ');
for(int i=0; i<words.Length-1; i++){
  if(words[i] == words[i+1]){
    //You have a match, do your stuff here!
  }
}
```

This way you know if 2 adjacent words are equal.

Answer (score -1):

I suppose you start with an array of words.

You should keep track of the words that are already processed, for example by adding them to a `HashSet`. Iterate the array front to back and for each not-yet processed word, start processing:

- Create a list of all word indices. For your example, the word `spring` would have the indices

  `0, 2, 3, 4`
- Combine each index with the following indices to pairs:

  `(0, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 4)`
- Split your pairs into Next-To-Pair and Combo-pair, by checking if their index difference is `1`

  `(2, 3), (3, 4)`

  `(0, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4), (2, 4)`

Note I don't know why you listed `(3, 4)` as Combo-Pair in the question, as far as I understand, it should be a Next-to-Pair. Please clarify the question if I misunderstood.